# How to tell TypeScript that two generic types are the same?

Tags: typescript, overloading

Consider the following overloaded function.

```js
function scan<A>(this: A[], f: (a: A, x: A) => A): A[];
function scan<A, B>(this: A[], f: (a: B, x: A) => B, init?: B): B[] {
    if (init === undefined) {
        const result = [this[0]];
        for (let i = 1; i < this.length; i++) {
            result.push(f(result[i - 1], this[i]));
        }
        return result;
    }

    const result = [init];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        result.push(f(result[i], this[i]));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that when `init` is not provided, the generic type `B` should be the same as `A`. How do I tell this to TypeScript? Currently, TypeScript complains that `A` is not assignable to `B` and vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) has a set of *call signature declarations* which determine how the function can be called, and (assuming the function is implemented and not just declared) a single *implementation*.  The implementation signature *is not callable*.

---

In your example code, you have a single call signature

```
// call signature
function scan<A>(this: A[], f: (a: A, x: A) => A): A[];
```

and an implementation

```
// implementation
function scan<A, B>(this: A[], f: (a: B, x: A) => B, init?: B): B[] {
    /* snip */
}
```

But this does not seem to be what you intend.  You really want those signatures both to be call signatures, like this:

```
// call signatutes
function scan<A>(this: A[], f: (a: A, x: A) => A): A[];
function scan<A, B>(this: A[], f: (a: B, x: A) => B, init?: B): B[];

// implementation
function scan(...) {
```

So the question is: what should the implementation signature be?

---

TypeScript's compiler is not able to check the implementation by checking it against each call signature separately.  There was a suggestion to do this at [microsoft/TypeScript#13235](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13235), but it was closed as too complex to implement.  Instead, what the compiler does is make sure that the implementation signature *parameters* can handle the parameters from each of the call signatures, and make sure that the implementation signature *return type* can handle the return return types from each of the call signatures.  That is, the return type can be the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the call signatures' return types.  This is not type safe (because you might be returning the wrong type for a particular call signature), but convenient.

For better or worse, such loose checking is the way TypeScript's overload implementation works.  So you need to be careful when you write overloaded functions.

---

Anyway, that means the implementation needs to be something like this:

```
// implementation signature
function scan<A, B>(this: A[], f: (a: B | A, x: A) => A, init?: B | A) {
    if (init === undefined) {
        const result = [this[0]];
        for (let i = 1; i < this.length; i++) {
            result.push(f(result[i - 1], this[i]));
        }
        return result;
    }

    const result = [init];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        result.push(f(result[i], this[i]));
    }
    return result;
}
```

It's not perfect by any means, but it's probably the best we can get if we want to put these two separate behaviors into a single overloaded function.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5A9jKSDeBYAUAUsUgPSlLwgA21SUAlgOagAuArgE4REkBm7YPFYM0welWAAeAIIA+ABSsAFgygAuJDIDaAXQA0SPpoUhNMwwA9zASiQBeOVpvm9AbgK9i5JAzAxqCEhgVhARMS8jQWFRcShJWUMAIUUVNVcDIxMzJCSrWwcnPN9gBlYAfk0kl1y9HEiSXz4kBQZS1gd7eyRBABMIPjaIXrs8fEaJkngxKA7uKHZqDu7tNKhtAAZdXQ9xyYm+NE4WwI6GByQARjdfJCkkNYA6QOAmFRuGAGpP0Yb9xvmi1Yjxg7CgygUfAUgKW2nOAForpk1nDdDYbLt-o0AL5-SbcDiccQw1iY-a4wh7SbTYCzJAki5w9o7PFGI4nCBnC4bD53B6qKDPCCvd6+b6-KlYkkgsEQqEk1GGFEMNEY1kU-4ErjE6BAsnECkUgg+Ki0ejMNhcaAEARCcJxBLyJQCjKGYwtHIWJDWZyFZwZXa2mJiCQgaRelLO9JaPRu7JVfK+xy5QxtMqVXI1JLuTz4Hx+AJBYWhe3mlhhK026Kl+JhxK5VIumOZd2mKpIAA+WkTMjsya9aYq7a7vfqkoYzVa7U63T6AyGIzH-xpdIZKxRWxZksah2OClOt2611u9yeLzeyg+4qXWOI0tB4Mh0N1sIRSKVAtR6P1Ew1+y1RL0i+pKREakornMwGMoOW47uy+6coeSA8ie-JqEKIqXmKPw3viwEyo+8rAYqaHrCq36gZEAE6gsSy7BSQA)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to type check by weakening the implementation signature. Lesson learned, the implementation signature must always be a combination of the overloaded signatures.

```js
const SCAN_EMPTY_NO_INIT = 'Scan of empty array with no initial value';

type Reducer<A, B> = (acc: B, a: A) => B;

function scan<A>(this: A[], f: Reducer<A, A>): A[];
function scan<A, B>(this: A[], f: Reducer<A, B>, init: B): B[];
function scan<A, B>(this: A[], f: Reducer<A, A | B>, init?: B): (A | B)[] {
    const { length } = this;
    let i = 0, result = [typeof init === 'undefined' ? this[i++] : init];
    if (length < i) throw new TypeError(SCAN_EMPTY_NO_INIT);
    const j = i;

    while (i < length) {
        result.push(f(result[i - j], this[i]));
        i++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Note that the function can't be called with the implementation signature. Hence, you can't use this function in unintended ways, to create an array of `A`s or `B`s.